# get the name of the selected radio button from button group

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, buttongroup

I want to return selected radio button name from button group in java :

```
ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
bg.add(radiobutton1);
bg.add(radiobutton2);
bg.add(radiobutton3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can loop through the radio buttons, for each button if isSelected() is true then call button.getText() to get the name.

```
for (AbstractButton button : bg.getElements())
    if (button.isSelected())
        return button.getText();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,but how can i do this loop?.

Comment: for (Enumeration<AbstractButton> buttons = bg.getElements(); buttons.hasMoreElements();) {
 AbstractButton button = buttons.nextElement();
 
 if (button.isSelected()) {
  return button.getText();
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want the button name? It isn't of much use. You can, however, get the all of the button references using `bg.getElements()`, and you can get the text of each of those references with `button.getText()`, both of which are of much more use than the name you gave the button. If you REALLY want the name, you can create the buttons and then call `radiobutton1.setName("radiobutton1")` and then use `getName()` on the reference.

Comment: thanks,but i want to know which radio button is selected by user,how can i do it ?

Comment: this is an answers to question and i want to know the name of the selected button.

Comment: If you add an EventListener to the button, then in its actionPerformed() method the event.getSource() will return the selected button: `if (event.getSource() == radiobutton1) {...}`